# Prove: $x_n\to p \iff$ Eventually All The Elements Of The Sequence Are In A Neighborhood

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $M$ be a metric space and let $p\in M$ and $\{x_n\}$ a sequence in $M$ so $x_n\to p$ iff for all neighborhood $u$ of $p$ there is $n_0$ such that for all $n_0<n_1: x_{n_1}\in u$

$\Rightarrow:$ Let there be an open neighborhood $u$ of $p$ be definition of an open set around each element of the set there in an open ball such that the ball is contained in the set, in particular $p\in u$ so there is an open ball $B(p,\epsilon)$ such that $B(p,\epsilon)\subseteq u$ now because $x_n\to p$ for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $n_0$ such that for all $n_0<n_1:x_{n_1}\in B(p,\epsilon)$ so for all $u$ we can find $\epsilon$ s.t for all $n_0<n: x_n\in u$

$\Leftarrow:$ For all neighborhood $u$ of $p$ there is $k_0$ such that for all $k_0<k_1: x_{k_1}\in u$ let $u$ be the open ball around $p$ namely $B(p,\epsilon)$ so $x_{k_1}\in B(p,\epsilon)$ and by definition $x_n\to p$

Is the proof redundant all that that we have to say is that an open neighborhood $u$ is an open ball and vice versa?

Comment: How are you relating the open ball $B(p,\epsilon)$ to $u$ in the $\Leftarrow$ direction?  In addition, how are the $x_{k_1}$'s in $B(p,\epsilon)$?

Comment: I have a definition "a neighborhood of $p$ is an open set $u$ s.t $p\in u$"

Comment: You are not allowed to choose $u$. $u$ is given. You have to say that because $u$ is open it contains a whole ball around $p$. Depending on the text, sometimes people don't assume that neighborhoods are open, but instead assume that they do contain an open set containing the point. Then you can place the open ball inside that open.

Comment: Yes, you can say these statements, but there are gaps in the justification.  That definition of an open set is correct, but how is $\epsilon$ related to that statement?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the proof

Comment: @arugula this is what my lecturer wrote I will translate and quote "if the claim hold for a neighborhood u, in particular its holds for neighborhood of the type $B(p,\epsilon)$"

Comment: Yes, the statement your lecturer wrote is "$B(p,\epsilon)$ is a type of neighborhood."  Not, "Every neighborhood is of type $B(p,\epsilon)$"  A ball is a *special* type of neighborhood.

Comment: @MichaelBurr got it thanks